# How to add live search to Rails 4.2?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-4, livesearch

I've been attempting to create a simple search form which responds to AJAX on my Rails 4.2 application. I've attempted every tutorial I could find, but still to no avail.

- http://railscasts.com/episodes/240-search-sort-paginate-with-ajax
- http://aymeric.gaurat.net/2010/how-to-develop-live-search-textbox-in-ruby-on-rails/
- [Ruby on Rails Live Search (Filtering)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24255691/ruby-on-rails-live-search-filtering),
- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EqzwLUni2PM)

This is my search method:

```html
  def self.search(search)
    search ? where('name LIKE ?', "%#{search}%") : all
  end
```

My index action on the controller:

```
  # GET /ticket_types
  # GET /ticket_types.json
  def index
    @ticket_types = TicketType.search(params[:search]).order(sort_column + " " + sort_direction).paginate(per_page: 10, page: params[:page])
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html {render 'index'}
      format.json {render json: @ticket_types.map(&:name)}
    end
  end
```

My filter:

```
  <form>
    <fieldset>
      <legend>Filter</legend>
        <%= form_tag path, remote: true, method: 'get', id: id do %>
          <%= hidden_field_tag :direction, params[:direction] %>
          <%= hidden_field_tag :sort, params[:sort]%>
          <p>
            <%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search], id: 'filter_search_autocomplete', data: {autocomplete_source: ticket_types_path} %>
            <%= render 'button_submit', name: nil, id:"search_button" %>
          </p>
        <% end %>
      </fieldset>
    </form>
```

The submit button:

```html
  <%= submit_tag "Search", name: name, class: 'button', id: id, remote: true %>
```

My ticket_types.coffee

```
jQuery ->
  $('#filter_search_autocomplete').autocomplete
  source: $('#filter_search_autocomplete').data('autocomplete-source')
```

And my index partial:

```html
<p id="notice"><%= notice %></p>

<%= render 'registry_filter', path: ticket_types_path, id: "ticket_search_filter" %>
<%= render 'ticket_types' %>
<br>
<section id="content-area"></section>
<div>
  <%= render 'button_link', button_name: "Create", path: new_ticket_type_path, id: 'create' %>
  <%= render 'button_link', button_name: "Back", path: ticket_types_path, id: 'back_button' %>
</div>
```

Any ideas on how could I have a livesearch box like Facebook? For example, I'd like that each time the user types a letter on the box, it shows about 5 results of registries that contain the given word, and then use this search asset as a partial to be able to use on other models of the application. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Well first of all, I would recommend using some sort of backend like ElasticSearch, if you know about ElasticSearch then let me know I will write an answer for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have done something along the lines in which are very similar to what you are trying to accomplish.

If you are storing everything in database then one of the things I would do is to convert the data to json in your rails controller.

Once you have your data converted to json simply create the input field in your rails form in which will have the autocomplete functionality.

Down below the you should pass the json object path to your data option.

Example:
`<%= f.text_field :some_name, data: {autocomplete_source: some_name_path} %>`

In your controller you should do something like so. Order and Where could be declared in your model (preferred way) as scopes.

```
  def index
    @some_name = SomeName.order(:field_name).where("feild_name like ?", "%#{params[:term]}%")

    respond_to do |f|
      f.json { render json: @some_names.map(&:field_name) }
    end
  end
```

The tool I used after the above was implemented was: [autocomplete](https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/)

Hope the above helps. If not this [railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/399-autocomplete-search-terms) episode should get you going in the right direction.

Comment: Thanks @coletrain! It was suggested to use a previous railscast to get the autocomplete going: [link](http://railscasts.com/episodes/102-auto-complete-association-revised), I managed to get it to work as expected when it loaded it all on the page, but couldn't get it to work while collecting the data from the database, it shows all the registries on the database and not only those that match the specific characters being typed, I'll update the question to reflect the changes made.

Comment: @FilipeGorgesReuwsaat I have updated my answer with an example of how to pull the json data.

Comment: Thanks again @coletrain, I did what you said and now it's all working as expected ; )